# Why is the world in total chaos?

Tags: plot-explanation, children-of-men

In *Children of Men*, For some reason which we're not really told, the world is in total chaos.

Is there any background info anywhere about why it is so, and how does it correlate to the infertility problem?

Answer (score 7):

If the world was suddenly told, "Humanity will die out in approximately 50 years," with irrefutable evidence, societal structure and the world economy would pretty quickly crash from panic.

I don't remember if this is ever explicitly said, but there is a tone of global panic throughout the movie. The exact details of how aren't important, but the why is implied throughout the movie: people taking advantage of each other. That is a theme echoed throughout the movie, and is meant to contrast Theo's ultimate selflessness.

Comment: To add to your answer;  imagine what the world's response would be if we knew an asteroid would wipe us out in 10 days. Total anarchy because nothing matters anymore. But even if we move the deadline to 50 years; humanity's future is just as pointless. It's not about how long until it happens, it's about the finality of it when it inevitably happens (regardless of the time scale; as long as it's a given that it will happen).

Comment: I disagree. What happened is that women became infertile for one reason or another. To go from that to "irrefutable evidence" that "Humanity will die out in approximately 50 years" is... highly illogical. I'm sure all the world's top scientists are working on all kinds of solutions, both for restoring fertility and probably for other alternatives as well. In 50 years technology and science is almost guaranteed to have come up with something IMHO.

Comment: @Flater I think you didn't think this through. What you're saying is that if we know for a fact that humanity will at some point in time die out, even if that is in 1000, 10000 or 1 million years, there would be total anarchy and chaos today. IMHO, most likely not.

Comment: @BadCash: A single person cannot fully comprehend a timespan that far outmatches their own life expectancy. They can appreciate the mathematical size, that's not the same as considering it relevant to their own life decisions. You can see the same happening to global warming. As the "doom clock" gets closer, people get more interested in its existence. In CoM, people cannot procreate anymore. Humanity is done for once the existing people are gone. This completely destroys the need to leave something behind for your descendants; and that means little to no consequences to actions.

Comment: @BadCash: `What happened is that women became infertile for one reason or another. To go from that to "irrefutable evidence" that "Humanity will die out in approximately 50 years" is... highly illogical.` How is this illogical? How are you expecting humanity to survive if no one can procreate anymore? Where are the new humans coming from? Also, you are vastly underestimating the power of insecurity and the dread of impending doom. It's like expecting people to leave a burning building in an orderly fashion. It's just not going to happen.

Comment: @Flater It's illogical because in 50 years a lot will have happened, and I would bet that science would come up with some way to restore fertility in one way or another. 50 years ago we hadn't landed on the moon, etc, etc. To re-use your analogy - I'm expecting the fire brigade to be able to put out the fire well within 50 years...

Comment: @BadCash: Emotions are not logical. If a somewhat credible person were to make an announcement _today_ that the world will end in 50 years, there will be a percentage of the population that already loses hope (as they see that credible person as an expert and defer to their judgment). This can be a small subset of people, but their anarchy can be the spark that starts global chaos. Secondly, the 50 years was not a given. People were simply infertile, with no timeline of extinction given (other than possible estimates). And any minor chaos causes earlier deaths and thus earlier extinction.

Comment: We'll obviously have to agree to disagree. IMHO, this answer is incorrect because "the world will end in 50 years" is not a fact, far from it. As for your comment on the small subset of people that will lose hope and start trouble - we have those today, and they've already been here in one form or another, yet we've always managed to keep them in check. Also, one might consider the case of someone who has been diagnosed with a terminal illness - they usually don't become crazy killers even though they know they are doomed within 6 months, even if they have no family or relatives to care about.

Comment: @BadCash Turn what you said the other way: It's been around 16 years and there's been absolutely no progress. It's gotten so bad that the one group that's still researching is seen as some shadowy organization. The events of the movie seem to be the first breakthrough anyone has ever had, though it's never explicitly stated whether any progress has been made before then. People tend to be pretty pessimistic when it comes to things they can't control. That's especially true if the people who can do something about it haven't delivered any results after that much time.